# Remove row if it starts with "RT"

Tags: regex, r, substring

How can I remove the entire row for those which start with "RT" in the first column?

```
    structure(list(text = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("@AirAsia @AirAsiaId finally they let us fly with 9.20 flight today. Manual boarding pass. Phew, that was a great relief!", 
    "@AirAsia your direct debit (Maybank) payment gateways is not working. Is it something you are working to fix?", 
    "RT @AirAsia: Kindly note that CIMB Direct Debit service will be unavailable tonight from (GMT+8) 1145hrs on 31 Jan until 0600hrs on 3 Feb 2â€¦", 
    "RT @AirAsia: Skipped breakfast this morning? Now you can enjoy a great breakfast onboard with our new breakfast meals! http://t.co/957ZaLjYâ€¦", 
    "xdek ke flight @AirAsia Malaysia to LA... hahah..bagi la promo murah2 sikit, kompom aku beli...", 
    "You know there is a problem when customer service asks you to wait for 103 minutes and your no is 42 in the queue. @AirAsia"
    ), class = "factor"), created = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("1/2/2014 16:14", "1/2/2014 17:00", "3/2/2014 0:54", 
    "3/2/2014 0:58", "3/2/2014 1:28"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("text", 
    "created"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I guess this would be the inverse duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23043075/1270695

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data frame is called `tweets`, then

```
no.rts <- tweets[grep("^RT ", tweets$text, invert=TRUE),]
```

will do what you want (and put the results in a new data frame called `no.rts`).

The `grep` statement says to ignore all lines in `tweets$text` that begin (`^`) with `RT`. Without the `invert=TRUE` it would *select* all the lines beginning with `RT`.

Comment: Hi, what if I want to remove the rows where the tweets$text ="NA"?

Comment: `no.nas <- tweets[!is.na(tweets$text),]` will give you that

Answer (score 4):

`grepl` also works.  Assuming `d` is the data set,

```
> d[!grepl("^RT", d$text), ]
##                        text        created
## 2 You know there...@AirAsia  3/2/2014 0:58
## 3 @AirAsia... great relief!  3/2/2014 0:58
## 4 @AirAsia...orking to fix?  3/2/2014 0:54
## 5 xdek ke flight ...        1/2/2014 17:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `stri_sub` function from `stringi` package to get first two characters and then check if they are equal to "RT":

```
require(stringi)
df[stri_sub(df$text,1,2)!="RT",]
```

Comment: check out `base::substr`.

Comment: stri_sub is better, because you can use negative value to count from the end of string. So to get last two characters stri_sub("abc123",-2,-1).

Comment: Hi, what if I want to remove the rows where the df$text ="NA"?

Answer (score 0):

All of the above work, I prefer subset because it is a bit more legible:

```
no.rts <- subset( tweets, ! grepl("^RT ", text) )
```

Comment: and it will also remove rows where `is.na(text)`.